# Need to call a script at logon based on hostname. Win 2k3 Domain and XP/7 workstations

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, group-policy

I have a user logon script.  I want to install printers based on hostname.
Inside this folder \domain.local\SYSVOL\domain.local\Policies{DF3F608C-8D78-934F-B79F-1965F3C4409B}\User\Scripts\Logon

I have cmd files for each host/workstation and the logon.cmd.

Terminal Servers are honoring the environment variable %clientname% but the workstations are not.

Relevant area of logon.cmd

```
rem Delete all existing printer connections
c:\windows\system32\con2prt.exe /f

rem Call workstation specific script for connecting to printers
%clientname%.cmd
```

Excerpt from clientname.cmdL:

```
rundll32 printui,PrintUIEntry /in /n\\fileserv\PhaserPS
rundll32 printui,PrintUIEntry /in  /n\\fileserv\CanonIR
rundll32 printui,PrintUIEntry /y  /n\\fileserv\CanonIR
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `%CLIENTNAME%` doesn't exist unless you have connected to a computer through RDP.  You should probably be calling `%COMPUTERNAME%` instead.

You could specify a different script for the terminal server that uses `%CLIENTNAME%`.  Or you can write a conditional in your script that will use `%CLIENTNAME%` if it is present, and if it isn't then try `%COMPUTERNAME%`.

Comment: Yes %COMPUTERNAME% is what I was missing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Zoredache has it right. As an aside, if you're looking to check if a variable is empty, you can do the following:

```
if not "%CLIENTNAME%"=="" echo all your code goes here
```

If you leave out the quotes, the batch interpret will just see "if not == echo all your..." and throw an error.